# На чем создавать gui для Linux на c#?

Tags: c#, gui, gtk

Есть задача написать графическую программу под Linux. До этого писал только на WinForms. Читал что под линукс для c# используют gtk#. Но на вики пишется что у gtk# частичная поддержка до 2.20, хотя уже сейчас уже вышла версия gtk 3.20. Есть ли какие-то другие решение для линукса или и с gtk# как-то работать можно?

Comment: mono поддерживает WinForm целиком, если память не обманывает. Не смотрели в этом направлении?

Answer (score 2):

[GtkSharp уже портирован под GTK3.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/gtksharp3-porting-guide/) Релиз 3.0 ещё не объявлен, но в репозиториях некоторых дистрибутивов уже есть.

А почему обязательно C#? Не хотите присмотреться к [Vala](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala)? Клон C#, сделанный на базе библиотек GNOME с хорошей интеграцией в экосистему.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще подобие Qt для c# - https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp. Проект вроде еще немного развивается(последний коммит был на прошлой неделе). Но у меня с этой библиотекой как-то не сошлось.